# Ext.app.Application does not create global variable using name config

Tags: extjs, extjs4

In the 4.0.2a docs: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/...pp.Application

I see this:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            items: {
                html: 'My App'
            }
        });
    }
});
```

"This does several things. First it creates a global variable called 'MyApp' - all of your Application's classes (such as its Models, Views and Controllers) will reside under this single namespace, which drastically lowers the chances of colliding global variables."

When I run this code, I do not see a global variable called MyApp... does anybody else have this problem?

Here is my entire app (in a single HTML page):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing ExtJS 4</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all-debug-w-comments.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.application({
        name: 'MyApp',
        launch: function() {
            Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
                items: {
                    html: 'My App'
                }
            });
        }
    });
    Ext.onReady(function() {
        alert(typeof MyApp);
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: i don't have this problem... how do you known that the global variable doesnt exists? can you post some of the code? maybe i can help you..

Comment: The variable MyApp is not accessible through the chrome console or firebug, and if I alert it's type, it says it is undefined... I pasted the very simple page I am using to demonstrate my problem

Answer (score 3):

it's not working because as the api states ([guide/mvc application architecture](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/docs/#/guide/application_architecture)):

"... All Ext JS 4 applications should only use a single global variable, with all of the application's classes nested **inside it**...".

If you try with this code:

```
 Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    appFolder: '/app',

    autoCreateViewport: true,

    launch: function() {
        console.log(MyApp);

    }
});
```

you will see that the global variable exists. You don't need to access the application from any other place than the application itself

Comment: Thank you... I understand that the app should have a global variable to hold all of the application classes, etc, as I have done that with many Ext 3.x apps... If I simply include a class called 'MyApp.view.Viewport' in my original code, I see that it works, so the application method must be trying to instantiate or load or reference a Viewport somewhere...

Comment: It seems like the name config is only used to set the loader path here: Ext.Loader.setPath(this.name, this.appFolder); (in the Ext.app.Application constructor)

Comment: that´s the entry point for the whole application, and where the app is initialized. can you be more specific about the exact issue you have? sorry, but i don't understand what is the problem that you have...

Comment: My original problem was that when I ran the script exactly as written in the docs at http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.app.Application, it did not create the global variable called MyApp, and I wanted to know why

Comment: i got it now... this link (http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/docs/#/guide/application_architecture) is the one i followed to develop my application and it´s another example that explains how the mvc works. only when i tried your exact code snippet (that is now the same from the api example) i could reproduce it. iĺl take a look at it and let you know

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error, and here are what I found.

In index.html:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});

Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    controllers: ['Test'],
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            items: {
                html: 'My App'
            }
        });
    }
});

Ext.onReady(function() {
    alert(typeof MyApp);
});
```

Create a small controller: app/controller/Test.js (/app has the same parent folder as /extjs)

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function() {
        console.log('The controller was initialised');
    }
});
```

When running, in Firebug you will see the MyApp global variable. However, a messagebox of 'undefined' still appeared for alert statement.

IMHO MyApp is an object to "maintains references to all of the models, views and controllers used by the app". Maybe extjs use some type of class "Dynamic loading"; so it will not create that global variable until there is something (controllers, views, models) to contain inside (I am not sure of this). In this case the variable must be created to contain the controller Test. However, I cannot explain the 'undefined' message for alert. Maybe at that time the Ext object is ready but "Dynamic loading" to create the viewport and the variable MyApp is not finished (not sure).

Hope this help.